# DB Design advice

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I'm planning on having several tables and I'm not quite sure how to go about designing the "whole thing".
Some help would be appreciated a lot! :)

I basically want to simulate a supermarket with recipes and ingredients.
So I was thinking about:

- Supermarket (name)
- Manufacturer (name) <- Has many products
- Products (amount, unit, name) <- Belongs to a manufacturer
- Amount (name) <- pivot with products amount
- Unit (name) <- pivot with products unit
- Ingredient (name, product) <- pivot with products

I'm kind of lost and I could image several solutions to go about this.
Ranging from multiple pivot tables with additinal pivot tables on them to real simple solutions which probably would include a decent portion of duplications across the tables.

I'm **especially interested** in your opinion about creating one "big" pivot table instead of multiple small ones:

- the "big" table would look something like this: "id" "ingredient_id" "product_id" "unit_id" ... so basically combining all pivot data on one big table.

- the "small" tables instead would look like "product_unit", "ingredient_product".
This question confuses me a lot. 

I kind of think that one big table would be best but I have no real idea to be honest.

I'm using Laravel and I'm pretty new to coding. If there is some kind of tool or something which would make your advice easier please let me know and I'll give it a try!

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of trouble first learning this with Laravel.  The great thing about this problem is you can use migrations to try something about, and roll it back if it isn't the best way.

Eloquent is based on the [active record pattern][1] so reading active record guides will be a great help.  You are aiming towards [database normalization][2].  I had better luck searching for 'database normalization rails' since RoR has been around for a long time and uses the same patterns.

I find it easier to keep doing what you were doing initially.

supermarket->has many->manufacturers

manufacturer->belong to many->supermarkets

product->belongs to one->manufacturer

manufacturer->has many->products

if a product always has an amount, and a product doesn't have many amounts, its usually better to just put it on the product table.  Normally a product would have wholesale_amt, retail_amt on the table.

If you have something like unit amounts:

```
unit_amount table:
id | title
1    pallet
2    case
3    box
4    single
```

...than you would put that in a separate table.  The reason is so that you could easily fix a misspelling, add a different amount in only one place.  If your developer misspells pallet in the update sql you don't end up with duplicate slightly misspelled records in the product table.

The product table would have a unit_amount column, which stores the id like this:

```
product table:
id | title | unit_amount
1  | water |   2
```

You only need a pivot table for many to many relationships.  A pivot table should allow you to do queries like this:

```
select * from manufacturer_product where manufacturer_id = 2
```

...and get every product for manufacturer 2.  The important thing is if the manufacturer has many products they are each a new record.

```
manufacturer_product table:
manufacturer_id | product_id
     2          |   1 
     2          |   8
     2          |   12
```

That system kind of falls apart if you have a warehouse_id on that table too and the manufacturer has 900 products but 2 warehouses:

```
manufacturer_id | product_id | warehouse_id
     2          |   1        |  1
     2          |   8        | 
     2          |   12       |
```

If you had a bunch of other columns you are 1.) returning a bunch of data you don't need 2.) can't use eloquent relationships anymore and 3.) what are you gonna name the table?

Dayle Rees has an awesome guide on eloquent relationships here that was really helpful for me:

http://daylerees.com/codebright/eloquent-relationships

> I basically want to load 'ingredients' which are related to 'products' which are related to 'manufacturers

For that you need to use the 'has many through' relationship.  It would look like this:

```
class Manufacturer extends eloquent {

    public function products {
        return $this->hasMany('Product');
    }

    public function ingredients {
         return $this->hasManyThrough('Ingredient', 'Product');  //has many ingredients through products
    }

}
```

You can query the relationship like this:

```
$manufacturer = new Manufacturer;
$ingredients = $manufacturer->ingredients();
```

The inverse works too:

```
class Ingredient extends eloquent {

    public function products {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Product');
    }

    public function manufacturer {
         //this is actually belongToThrough but they don't call it that
         return $this->hasManyThrough('Manufacturer', 'Product');
    }

}
```

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships

The inverse gets a bit more confusing, see the discussion here:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6161

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern
[2] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was super helpful! I'll try to implement it and see how far I'm able to get :) It would be nice if you could take a loot back once in a while. I'm trying to implement it now but I still have some decently big question marks in my head